# Ionic publish native deeplink plugin - doesn't works on iOS, works on Android

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I'm adding Deeplink plugin to my Ionic project using native plugin (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks/)

I've added it to the project with

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-deeplinks --variable URL_SCHEME=myapp --variable DEEPLINK_SCHEME=https --variable DEEPLINK_HOST=app.example.com --save 
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/deeplinks
```

This correctly added the following to config.xml

```
<plugin name="ionic-plugin-deeplinks" spec="~1.0.14">
    <variable name="URL_SCHEME" value="myapp" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_SCHEME" value="https" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_HOST" value="app.example.com" />
</plugin>
```

I've obtained the updated iOS certificates (both dev and distribution) to support "Associated Domains" in the App ID on https://developer.apple.com.

I've added https://app.example.com/apple-app-site-association that looks like

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "XXXXX.com.example",
                "paths": [ "*" ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm using Ionic Cloud Build to build apps https://apps.ionic.io/apps/

The Android links are working great.
But iOS links are not handled by the app and keep being opened by the browser.

I'm not sure where is the problem.
What can I do to fix it or at least how can I see what's broken?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can debug your app in code to check whether the url ' https://app.example.com/apple-app-site-association ' is requested during starting. So you can make sure or that using some proxy tool like Charles.

And, you need to check the project target config like entitlement and capabilities.